# Starting with functions in CreateJS / Animate

Tags: javascript, createjs, animate-cc

i'm new in Animate/CreateJS, and i would like to know how to make this to work.
What i want is when i mouseover one object, the other appears from 0 alpha to 1.
I searched google but i cannot find anything that helps me with this issue.

The code is this one:

```
var frequency = 3;
stage.enableMouseOver(frequency);
this.movieClip_1.addEventListener("mouseover", fl_MouseOverHandler);

function fl_MouseOverHandler()
{

// Execute movieclip 2 function

}


var movieClip_2_FadeInCbk = fl_FadeSymbolIn.bind(this);
this.addEventListener('tick', movieClip_2_FadeInCbk);
this.movieClip_2.alpha = 0;

   function fl_FadeSymbolIn()
   {
   this.movieClip_2.alpha += 0.01;
   if(this.movieClip_2.alpha >= 1)
   {
        this.removeEventListener('tick', movieClip_2_FadeInCbk);
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is that question tagged jquery?

Comment: made a mistake without notice!!!

Comment: This isn't AS3, it's JS/CreateJS.

Comment: Also, post the current behavior/output you are seeing.

Comment: @HomerO I removed the [actionscript-3] tag and added relevant tags... please update your title and description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've written is not far off. You have an alpha fade ticker, you just need to add the tick listener when you want to start the fade in. Also make sure to use `.bind(this)` when passing in any handler functions that accesses `this` in them, or you will run into problems:

```
var frequency = 3;
stage.enableMouseOver(frequency);
this.movieClip_1.addEventListener("mouseover", fl_MouseOverHandler.bind(this));

function fl_MouseOverHandler() {
    this.addEventListener('tick', movieClip_2_FadeInCbk);
}

this.movieClip_2.alpha = 0;

var movieClip_2_FadeInCbk = fl_FadeSymbolIn.bind(this);
function fl_FadeSymbolIn() {
   this.movieClip_2.alpha += 0.01;
   if (this.movieClip_2.alpha >= 1) {
       this.removeEventListener('tick', movieClip_2_FadeInCbk);
   }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a [`Tween`](http://www.createjs.com/docs/tweenjs/classes/Tween.html):

```
var frequency = 3;
stage.enableMouseOver(frequency);
this.movieClip_1.addEventListener("mouseover", fl_MouseOverHandler.bind(this));

this.movieClip_2.alpha = 0;

function fl_MouseOverHandler() {
    createjs.Tween.get(this.movieClip_2).to({alpha: 1}, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Yes, understand that, but the problem is that the code i posted does not work because give me the error  "cannot access a property "alpha" of a null object reference", so i know that movieclip2 is not defined but when i define it, i got WSOD.

Comment: I don't think you do understand. ;) First, that error should have been included in your original post. Second, I was able to guess that was (one of) your errors based on your original code, and this answer *fixes that issue* using `bind(this)` (re-read the answer for that part). Try the code and see if it doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: You got the point, i made the code again instead of copy/pasting your code. So i will compare the two codes to know what i was doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the Tween class:

```
private var buttonTween:Tween;

button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onRollOver);
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, onRollOut);

private function onRollOver(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if (buttonTween && buttonTween.isPlaying) {
        buttonTween.stop();
    }
    buttonTween = new Tween(e.target, "alpha", Elastic.easeOut, button.alpha, 1, 3, true);
}

private function onRollOut(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if (buttonTween && buttonTween.isPlaying) {
        buttonTween.stop();
    }
    buttonTween = new Tween(e.target, "alpha", Elastic.easeOut, button.alpha, 0, 3, true);
}
```

Feel free to customise the parameters however you need/want.

To reduce code duplication you could even place that in a function that you call with just a few arguments like so:

```
private function tweenButtonAlpha(button:ButtonObject, endAlpha:Number):void {
    if (buttonTween && buttonTween.isPlaying) {
        buttonTween.stop();
    }
    buttonTween = new Tween(button, "alpha", Elastic.easeOut, button.alpha, endAlpha, 3, true);
}
```